# Change order of autocomplete suggestions : Function lib.es6.d.ts

Tags: javascript, typescript, autocomplete, webstorm

So I constantly write the term `function`. And I'm bothered by having to go 7 steps to get to it.

My WebStorm setting is currently:

```
Case Sensitive Completion: None
```

I can see why capital letter Function is showing up with my current settings. But I'm not sure:

- Why there is 3 of them?
- Why lower case one isn't the first one in the list?
- Why WebStorm doesn't actually learn my autocomplete preferences because I used `function` 100s of times and `Function` none time. I don't even know what it does. Should I be using it?

So I want to somehow move the classic lower cased function up in the autocomplete options. How can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Not answering your exact question, but: consider creating custom Live Template with `fun` as abbreviation, then typing `fun[TAB]` (TAB as an expand key, could also be Space or Enter) will expand into whatever content you put there in template; such entry will be first in the list. https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Live+Templates+%28Snippets%29+in+PhpStorm **P.S.** Yes, IDE *should* have learned and showed `function` as first choice if you have choose it so many times before. No ideas on what might be causing it now, but try `File | Invalidate Caches...` and restart if you wish.

Comment: Good advice, I'll try this if I can't find a proper solution. I tried invalidating, didn't change. But I did notice that this only happens when I'm writing a function inside a function. It doesn't happen inside modules or outside any namespace.

Comment: *"But I did notice that this only happens when I'm writing a function inside a function."* That explains such behaviour a bit -- priority is given to actual functions in such context. if you feel it's too "aggressive" -- consider filing a ticket at WebStorm's Issue Tracker (as it's a JS/TS context) -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB

Comment: Heres how I did like you said: http://prntscr.com/hj2qig